# How to store big lists in memcached?

Tags: memcached

I have a multi-tenant site that stores people's information across multiple MySQL tables. I can pull from different tables when I need different information about a list people.

I've just started out using Memcached and I rather like it. I'd like to use it to speed up this process of filtering through the lists of people.

My question is how would I effectively store people's information in memcached so when queries are processed, whether simple or complex, I don't have to load everything from the MySQL database each time? When I say complex, I will be querying multiple MySQL tables to find the people list I need.

Some thoughts I had:

1. Store ALL people's information (including info from linked MySQL tables) in memcached. Then when I need a specific group of people or need to generate a complex report, I filter through the array of people from memcached rather than query MySQL... The thing is, there could be thousands of people with 100's of rows of information each and I'm not sure if memcached can  handle that amount of data.
2. Store people each time a new report or view is created. It will save it so if that same report is generated, it will pull from memcached.

Any insight you can give would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

memcached is intended to be a cache, not a database. Do *not* store large chunks of information in it, especially since it will likely be faster to query the database for a specific piece of information rather than load it all from the cache, parse it out, and then find it.